# Invoking raise(signal) terminates c++ program

Tags: c++, signals

I have two program running on my Raspberry Pi.  One interfaces with a user, the other listens for messages and updates a message file when directed.  I want the other to signal to the first that the messages have been updated so the first can reload the message file.  I though a SIGUSR1 signal would do what I need.  However, when I raise the signal, it terminates my program, which still needs to continue listening for new messages.  I therefore constructed the test case program "test_raise.cpp":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
int main(){
    std::cout << "Ready to raise SIGUSR1." << std::endl;
    std::raise(SIGUSR1);
    std::cout << "SIGUSR1 has been raised." << std::endl;    
}
```

I am using this compiler:
gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1)

which generates the following output

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$./test_raise
Ready to raise SIGUSR1.
User defined signal 1
pi@raspberrypi:~$
```

Note that the 2nd text output is not produced.  None of the documentation I have looked at indicates that raise terminates the issuing program. (Have I missed something?)

Is this a normal function of raise?  Is there a way to do signals without terminating the program?  What is my better alternative?

Thanks...

Based on a response, I have a program (invoked prior to the raise program) which has a handler for the USR1 signal:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
#include <unistd.h>
bool flag;

void signalHandler( int signum ) {
    std::cout << "Interrupt signal (" << signum
                            << ") received." << std::endl;
    flag = true;
    exit(signum);  
}

int main () {
    signal(SIGUSR1, signalHandler);  
    flag = false;

    while(1) {
        std::cout << "Sleeping...." << std::endl;
        if (flag){
            std::cout << "SIGUSR1 reception noted by main. "
                      << std::endl;
            flag = false;
        }
        sleep(1000*1000);  //  sleep 1 second
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now there is a handler, but the messages was never received and the raise program still terminates prior to the final message.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't installed a signal handler to catch and deal with `SIGUSR1` then the default behaviour is to terminate the process.

If you intend to handle the signal, then install an appropriate signal handler and do what you need to do to handle the signal. (Remember that there are *very* few things you are allowed to do in a signal handler).